# show div *ngIf router active navbar

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I try to show a div under each link in a navbar as long as we are in that active page. I'm iterating every link with * ngFor

What I need is something like this:

[image]

But what I get is this:
[image]

Here my code:

component.html

```
<li class="nav-item mx-1" *ngFor="let link of links">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="link.url" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
  {{link.nombre}}
  </a>
  <div *ngIf="getRouteActive()" class="bg-primary" style="height: 4px;"></div>
</li>
```

component.ts

```
getRouteActive() {
  return this.router.url === '/item1';
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's showing right off the bat so unless you have a class that has display:none attached to it, it will always show that one. I'm not as familiar with Angular syntax but you would need something like onLoad do this

Comment: If the underline comes from the `<div class="bg-primary" ...>`, you should pass the link to `getRouteActive` and test if that link is the active one. For example: `getRouteActive(link) { return this.router.url === link.url; }`. A more standard approach is to use the `active` class to style the anchor tag itself, for example by setting the bottom border.

Comment: @Connors had not thought about that approach but it sounds easier I think, thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `url` as a parameter to your function.

```
getRouteActive(url) {
      // I assume your url has a forward slash already
      return this.router.url === url;
    }
```

Then in your `template`

```
<li class="nav-item mx-1" *ngFor="let link of links">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="link.url" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
      {{link.nombre}}
      </a>
      <div *ngIf="getRouteActive(link.url)" class="bg-primary" style="height: 4px;"></div>
</li>
```

That should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using CSS:

```
.nav-item {
    div {
       display: none;
    }

   .active + div{
       display: block;
   }
}
```